# POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD (LARAVEL)

Tags: php, laravel

I am pulling in standard php code from a file called **test5.php** into a file called **subscription.blade.php**.

The code **works great in the standard php file** and **almost works** **in Laravel blade view**.  The prompt and associated style displays correctly.  However, once one of the two array variables are entered into the password box it gives me nothing but a **500 error**.  When the same code is tested outside of the blade in a standard file it works fine.  I considered .htaccess issues since one directly was effected and not the other and came up empty on troubleshooting attempts.  I am of course new to Laravel.  I tried to use the code directly in the blade using @php and @endphp directives but did not work so I went with the include. It doesn't seem to like the last line Thanks for any insight on this.

I've pulled in the following code from test5.php into subscription.blade.php using @include('test5')

```
 <?php
include('easy-protect.php');
$options = array(
        'skin'     => 6,   
    );
   protect(array('testing','123456'), $options);
?>
```

Error Log:

```
[2020-01-01 21:39:08] local.ERROR: Call to a member function send() on null {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function send() on null at /home/www/mywebsite.com/index.php:56)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"}    

[2020-01-01 21:39:08] local.ERROR: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in /home/www/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:123
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/www/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(100): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
    #1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
    #2 {main}
      thrown {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in /home/www/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:123
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/www/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(100): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
    #1 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError))
    #2 {main}
      thrown at /home/www/mywebsite.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:123)
    [stacktrace]
    #0 {main}
    "}
```

index.php:56

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send(); (This is LINE 56)

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

HandleExceptions.php:100

```
/**
 * Handle an uncaught exception from the application.
 *
 * Note: Most exceptions can be handled via the try / catch block in
 * the HTTP and Console kernels. But, fatal error exceptions must
 * be handled differently since they are not normal exceptions.
 *
 * @param  \Throwable  $e
 * @return void
 */
public function handleException($e)
{
    if (! $e instanceof Exception) {
        $e = new FatalThrowableError($e);
    }

    try {
        self::$reservedMemory = null;

        $this->getExceptionHandler()->report($e);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //
    }

    if ($this->app->runningInConsole()) {
        $this->renderForConsole($e);
    } else {
        $this->renderHttpResponse($e); (This is LINE 100)
    }
}
```

HandleExceptions.php:123

```
/**
 * Render an exception as an HTTP response and send it.
 *
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return void
 */
protected function renderHttpResponse(Exception $e)
{
    $this->getExceptionHandler()->render($this->app['request'], $e)->send();(This is Line 123)
}
```

1/5/2020 Update :  Findings So Far:
**1**. @adilbo placing the code at the very beginning of the blade file didn't make any change.
**2**. In fact I deleted all code from the subscription.blade.php file and left only the easy protect code with exactly the same results. This leads me to believe that it is a filename association in Laravel where perhaps I could make an exclusion but where?
**3**. I tried the code in my own custom named php blade view in the same directory and it works fine. Using the code inside of the specific filename does not work. I hope that makes sense.

**Cause Error:  Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.**

Comment: FYI there are typically more array options  but I cut them down here for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You have tried this way.... I tried to use the code directly in the blade using `<?php and ?>` directives.

Comment: if you are using laravel framework please check logs in storage/logs  folder there will be log please check error details in that file

Comment: I have tried both <?php and @php inline with no success.  I am having success on getting it to display but the last line protect array is throwing an error when executed

Comment: I've checked the logs as per the advice. For the sake of this comment I'll condense the error output. 1st -  `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:123`   .This line refers specifically to this code `/**
     * Render an exception as an HTTP response and send it.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $e
     * @return void
     */
    protected function renderHttpResponse(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->getExceptionHandler()->render($this->app['request'], $e)->send();
    }`    @SagarSainkar

Comment: @SagarSainkar The other error log reference is to the index.php `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
$response->send(); (<-- This line specifically)`

Comment: `Stack trace:
#0 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php(100): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
#1 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))`

Comment: `#2 {main}
  thrown {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Uncaught Error: Call to a member function send() on null in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php:123`

Comment: These comments aren't super friendly on the eyes with the error logs.  I have updated the above information more legibly into the original post.  Thank you.

Comment: `include` and `@include` are not strictly the same. `@include` is meant to include other blade views , while `include` is meant for including general PHP files.

Comment: @apokryfos thank you for that clarification on include for blade views.  Unfortunately, the easy-protect.php contains a licensed product that wouldn't be very professional of me to share.  I can tell you what it does and that it works just fine outside of the Laravel framework.  Even inside the framework, no errors point to this file.  In short, it allows me to include the file in places where I'd like to offer a makeshift password protected page.  It looks for a few options of what skin I want to load for the form, using md5 hash, block IP etc.  Include it in a regular php file and works fine

Comment: Please make sure that you include the 'protect' script at the very beginning of your template, so that no header is send to the browser - maybe that is also a problem.

Comment: It all depends on what the script does. It seems to be interrupting the standard Laravel request/response lifecycle so without any understanding on why I'm afraid you're on your own. If its a purchased library you might have some success asking the developers if they have a Laravel friendly version

Comment: As I understand from error log $response->send(); (This is LINE 56) as its core function of laravel and its unexpected error on it, there may be some issue with an included file that is disturbing laravel response mechanism

Comment: Thank you all, I will investigate further and test off these suggestions and leave feedback.

Comment: Findings So Far: 1. @adilbo placing the code at the very beginning of the blade file didn't make any change.  2.  In fact I deleted all code from the subscription.blade.php file and left only the easy protect code with exactly the same results.  This leads me to believe that it is a filename association in Laravel where perhaps I could make an exclusion but where?  3. I tried the code in my own custom named php blade view in the same directory and it works fine.  Using the code inside of the specific filename does not work.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Cause Error: Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: Be advised that I have figured out this problem. I will post a structured answer in the next day or two.  In summary, I had to create a post route in Laravel web.php for the page in question that allowed POST data and assigned a controller.  As of now I have the page excluded from CSRF token to verify that it is working.  I will add CSRF protection as a proper fix to avoid compromising security for functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I was getting a random 500 error which is the worst.  To get a better understanding of the error I added the below to **/app/Exceptions/Handler.php**
   public function render($request, Exception $exception)

> ```
> public function render($request, Exception $exception)  
>     {  
>           return parent::render($request, $exception);  
>     }
> ```

This generated an error detailing that the POST method was not allowed.

2. The POST method isn't allowed in this case because a route isn't defined for it in **/routes/web.php** . In my case, I had GET route but not a defined POST route.  This is one of many security features in the Laravel framework as I understand it. Defining a new route with GET or POST would look like one of the below examples:

> ```
>  /* mypage */
>
>  Route::get('/mypage', 'CommonController@view_mypage');
>  Route::post('/mypage', 'CommonController@view_mypage'); 
>  /*mypage*/
> ```

1. Once you've successfully added the route the 500 error will now go away.  However, you now have a 419 PAGE EXPIRED Error (lucky me).  This error is generated as another one of Laravel's security efforts when it can not locate a [CSRF_TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf) form input in the page HTML body.  It's looking for this because I've introduced a form by using the included easy-protect.php file in my case.  You have two options to free yourself of this error (that I know of).

**Option 1** (least secure) - Exclude the page from being checked for a CSRF Token by adding the following code example to **/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

> ```
>     protected $except = [     'https://mywebsite.com/mypage',
>      ];
> ```

**Option 2** (most secure)- Get your newly introduced form / page to comply with CSRF protection whether it is inline or as part of the included file depending on your unique scenario.  You can learn more about that from Laravel [HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

**IMPORTANT**: Once you are finished with this and hopefully you've had some success, don't forget to go back to **/app/Exceptions/Handler.php** and comment out the below line of code.  Otherwise, any errors the site generates can easily expose all of your database credentials and API keys within the report.

> `//return parent::render($request, $exception);`

This answer is unique to my scenario but will be very common if you try to integrate other PHP products such as forms into the Laravel framework.  Again, please note that I am not a Laravel expert or even moderately knowledgeable.  I've had to learn all of this through experiencing this problem.  I share this detailed answer in hopes to get someone else who is lost on the right path.